# How can I create a custom border using the same material as the world boundary?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When you reach the edge of a world at around X/Z 29,999,984, you encounter a barrier that can only be passed through teleportation.

[image]

I would like to use them as a barrier around a PVP arena to keep all the players from wandering too far. However, it doesn't seem to be a normal block like [barrier blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Barrier) are. The [minecraft wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/World_boundary) on the world boundary doesn't mention them having a block ID or really any other way to move and control them.

I've also tried pressing F3 to see if that would reveal what the boundary's ID is, but it just shows the block behind it.

[image]

So, is there any way to move the world boundary, or use the same material as the boundary with `/fill` and other commands?

Comment: Oh, you cant go to farlands anymore?

Comment: @Moacir aren't the farlands a alpha and beta exclusive thing only?

Comment: @Moacir When did you last play Minecraft? Those were fixed over 7 years ago!

Comment: I've heard of them in the past but never pursued them. Just now I am learning it is not possible anymore :/

Comment: @Moacir supposedly they still exist in bedrock edition but were fixed in java edition a while ago. See https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Far_Lands.

Comment: Man. I'm really old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy:

[**/worldborder**](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/worldborder)

You can set the diameter by `/worldborder set <distance>`. For example `/worldborder set 5` results in this (a square of 5x5 blocks):

[image]

Moving the border is also possible by using `/worldborder center <x> <z>`, which will put the border around these coordinates.

Comment: Have you always been able to change the center?  I seem to remember that particular feature being distinctly absent when the world border first rolled out.

Comment: @MBraedley I just tested it by moving it 5 blocks out and it worked (on 1.13). I'm not sure when they added that.

Comment: Just adding something that may be useful to this: You can shrink or expand the world border over time by adding a time amount after the size set command: `/worldborder set <distance> <time>`

Comment: Oh.. battle royale borders inc.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki does technically direct you there, it's just not very apparent. It says:

> The boundary of the world has several "layers". The first layer is the world border, which lies at X/Z ±29,999,984 by default.

This has a link to the customisable world border, which you can modify with the [`/worldborder` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/worldborder) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/worldborder)).